# onTouch() method shows no usage

Tags: android

I'm trying to get pixel color from my image so that I can match the color and start an activity from a fragment. Can anybody help me out with this?[Here's my code with information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7b0C.png)

Comment: Add *@Override* above method. You need to set *setOnTouchListener* and implement *OnTouchListener* interface.

Comment: Can I get an example for this? Because I'm using this in a fragment, but I am confused where to implement the onTouchListener?

Comment: I have updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Now the code shows no error. But when I touch the image to scroll, the app stops. Can I know what is the error?

Comment: Accept this answer, and post your crash log.

Comment: I have put up the XML file. I am using scroll view. Now after having run my code, when I go to explore fragment and move to scroll the app stops.

Comment: Check updated code, As you are launching fragment using *startActivity()*.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code for more details.

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, container, false);
            view.setOnTouchListener(this);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Rect rectangle = new Rect();
            Window window = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getWindow();
            window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
            int statusBarHeight = rectangle.top;
            int contentViewTop = window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
            int titleBarHeight = contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;


            final int action = event.getAction();

            final int evX = (int) event.getX();
            final int evY = (int) event.getY();

            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    int touchColor = getHotspotColor(R.id.image_areas, evX, evY - statusBarHeight);
                    if (touchColor == Color.parseColor("ff9933")) {
                        /*Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), IndiaFragment.class);
                        startActivity(intent);*/
                        //TODO: IndiaFragment.class should be activity class not fragment
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public int getHotspotColor(int hotspotId, int x, int y) {
            ImageView img = Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(hotspotId);
            img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap hotspot = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());
            img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            return hotspot.getPixel(x, y);
        }
    }
```

If this will not work, then post your entire code.

Comment: I have shared the fragment activity with you. What I am trying to do here is using two images one in foreground and an invisible image with color patches in the background. So when I click on a particular color this code should launch a new activity.
Can you help me out with this?